# how to add a delay in a while loop. JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
        function falling()
        {
            isFalling = true;

            while (isFalling == true)
            {

                if (y < 120) {

                    y++;

                }
                else if (y == 120) {
                    isFalling = false;

                }

            }

        }
```

I have tried adding setTimeout(function() around the entire loop, around the if statement, around the y++. I don't know what i'm doing wrong. Any time I add any of these the page becomes unresponsive once the falling function is called. I'm well aware that this is probably  a duplicate question but the duplicate questions failed ti help.
                     { }, 100)

Comment: Do you have a global variable y?

Comment: why do you need a delay in the first place? Not clear what you are trying to accomplish as not enough details provided

Answer (score 1):

You would do it like this:

```
function falling(y) {
    if (y < 120) {
        setTimeout(falling.bind(this, y + 1), 100); // specify your delay.
    }
}

falling(0);
```

The question has indeed been answered several times, and the [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop) are really not that different from this.

Note that I removed the apparently global variable `isFalling`. If you do need that variable in other code, then you can keep that variable updated as follows:

```
function falling(y) {
    isFalling = y < 120;
    if (isFalling) {
        setTimeout(falling.bind(this, y + 1), 100); // specify your delay.
    }
}
```

Comment: While it is not 100% clear from the question, it appears that the intent is the management of a period of time where **isFalling** is **true**.  If so, then this answer needs a bit more code.

Comment: @JonSG, if that is true, the question would really need to specify this as a constraint. Anyway, I what needs to be added to the code to maintain such global state.

Answer (score 0):

I would use window.setInterval() instead, as you want it to repeat until a certain number

working plunkr:

https://plnkr.co/edit/TbpplnIShiaJR7sHDUjP?p=preview

```
function falling()
    {
        var isFalling = true; 
        var y=0;
        myInterval = window.setInterval(function() {
          y++;
          console.log(y);
          if (y== 120) {
            clearInterval(myInterval);
          }
        }, 100)
    }

falling();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the intent of calling **falling()** is to temporarily set the value of a global variable to **true** (as suggested by your current code), then this should do the trick.

```js
var isFalling = false;

function falling(fallDuration) {
  isFalling = true;
  console.log("now falling");

  setTimeout(function(){
    isFalling = false;
    console.log("landed");
  }, fallDuration || 1000);

}

falling();
```

I imagine though that you might actually want to *fall* and then continue doing something else.  In that case you probably want to look at a callback or into promises.  You might do a simple:

```js
var isFalling = false;

function falling(fallDuration, andThen) {
  isFalling = true;

  console.log("now falling");

  setTimeout(function() {
    isFalling = false;
    console.log("landed");
    andThen();
  }, fallDuration);

}

falling(1000, function(){ console.log("now standing"); });
```